# How to do custom error handling in next.js server side while in dev mode

Tags: next.js

if you take a look at my screenshot you can see that I'm getting a error message in my nextjs debugging console containing a bunch of useless `[object Object]` repetitions as stack trace.
I don't know what is causing it, and I can not put debug endpoints either because it is happening in nextjs internals.

I tried providing my own `_error` page, but it is only used in production, and while in dev mode you get no way to properly handle this kind of errors.

[image: error screenshot]

This really slows down my dev server and it is getting worse and worse. Is there any way I can override or step into this function so I can properly debug it?